# In-app purchase for iOS fails from time to time

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store

My problem is strange, and it seems that this problem is not mine, but I think I have to ensure it. I'm testing my game with the test account, and from time to time it fails with the message like "The product with this ID has not found in store". Or, to be precise, it succeeds and fails in turn, like "success"-"fail"-"sucess"-"fail". The ID is always the same. It works normally for Android. Is it a normal situation for AppStore?